# Sync issues w/ Outlook 2007 & Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007

User has been having sync issues for months now on 2 separate machines: Win XP & Win 7. Email that has been filed away in specific folders finds it way back into the inbox. It is usually old email and it finds it way to the top of the inbox.

Profile has been recreated and updates have been installed. Took her off 'Cached Exchange Mode' as well, no luck. Problem usually goes away after restarting Outlook, but not always.

Logs and troubleshooting on Exchange 2010 seem fine according to colleague (I don't have access). Any ideas or advice for basic troubleshooting procedures?

Comment: Please check with user and Exchange if possible to find ***all*** devices that are connected to Exchange or that the user has connected to Exchange in the past. We have had this issue specifically when Mac devices are synced, even when Mac devices don't show the problem, the problem will show itself on PCs, so it's important to get a complete list of devices that are synched.

Comment: The devices currently with an exchange account are Win 7 laptop and an iPhone5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the iPhone, from professional experience. My suggestion though is process of elimination: disable the syncing from one device at a time until the problem stops. The end user might complain but if the problem is that big of a pain then it will be worth it to get it resolved. If they absolutely ***must*** have 24/7 email and calendar access then hopefully you have owa enabled, other than that then it's just tough cookies.

I can't tell you how long to disable activesync on those devices, it's really as long as necessary until either the problem comes back or you're sure it's not going to come back.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've observed the problem only occurs when the user is travelling, i.e. outside of our LAN. Just wondering if that provides any additional insight.

Comment: it's possible the timezone could have something to do with it, but I stand by my first suggestion.